# Python normalizing a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some string like these:

```
allora, ciao lol
allora , ciao lol
allora ,ciao lol
allora,ciao lol
4,5 sia
```

The output must be

```
allora , ciao lol
allora , ciao lol
allora , ciao lol
allora , ciao lol
4,5 sia
```

I must do the same thing for the . character.
How can I must do that?

I tried this regex

```
[a-zA-Z],
```

but it doesn't recognize all of them... How can I find all the occurrences with a regex and replace them?

Comment: `4,5` does not need spaces inbetween?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes exact... it doesn't need spaces

Comment: Based on the example strings, what you want could be done by converting comma to space, splitting on whitespace to an array of 3 string elements, then printing those elements in the format you want which depends on whether or not the first element matches an integer.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?<=\D)\s*,\s*(?=\D)
```

and replace with `,` note white spaces around comma

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK8wL7/1)

Comment: Nice Regex, but I can't understand which function I can use to replace all string in a text!

Comment: I have also tested the regex with other symbols like . or : but it doesn't work... how can I adapt it ?

Comment: to use other symbols modify pattern to `(?<=\D)\s*[,.:]\s*(?=\D)`